# RoR: How to trigger a python script after every order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am rookie in RoR. I want to run a custom task after every order. To be more specific, I want to run a python script to update the quantity of the same prduct on another site.

So my question is, how can I trigger the script after every order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [after_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/after_filter). But this will block.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :update_product_count, :only => :new_order

  def new_order
    ...
  end

  private
  def update_product_count
    system "python /path/to/update/script.py"
  end
end
```

Or you can do it in background (I prefer [delayed jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem)

**Order model:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  private

  def update_product_count order_id
    # find products in this order and pass them to python script
    products = Order.find(order_id).products.map(&:id)
    system "python /path/to/update/script.py #{products}"
  end
end
```

**Orders controller:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def new_order
    order.new
    ...
    order.save!
    Order.delay.update_product_count(order.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run commands like ruby does. `python commands`, note that '' between.

Answer (score 0):

If Order is an ActiveRecord model, you can use an [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to run code after each Order is created. For example:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :update_count

  private

  def update_count
    system "python /path/to/script.py #{self.class.count}"
  end
end
```

If the publish script is likely to take a long time, you'll want to spawn a background job to run the script instead. There are a number of Ruby libraries to manage this for you; have a look at [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for a start.